# Need inputs for making a tool to insert preformatted comments in C/C++ source/header file

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to develop a tool that inserts comments in C/C++ source files in pre-defined formats.

The comments could be:

1. file headers <-> file names required
2. class comments <-> class name required
3. function comments <-> function name required

Following points are required to be taken mind:

1. If the comments are already there in right format then leave them intact.
2. If the comments are broken them fix them and insert them.

Some desirable but non important features:

1. Check and fix the indentation.
2. Check if any breaks are missing in their respective cases.

**Please suggest open-source / free libraries / logic to aid in this.**

Comment: I don't understand your first enumerated list. What does "<->" signify?

Comment: It sounds like editor templates to me. Reformatting and adding comment templates to file / class / function can be done by any state-of-the-art IDE (Eclipse, Visual Studio). So it may a good start to look what they do.

Comment: @tomalak-geretkal Here C/C++ refers to the fact that the source code could be either C or C++ or mixed.

Comment: @rene-richter I have already looked into those but what I want is an automated tool that should not include opening each file in an editor or IDE, rather I want to right a tool that would do some file editing and save it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you 've got two choices:

- Generate the whole c/c++ code and headers from a template or scripting language and use this one to insert the preformated comments. This is of course not an option if you still got a lot of code.
- Or you need a tool to parse the code into sth. you can further use. You could try doxygen to generate html, xml or some other format. Problem would still be, how to get the generated documentation back into your sources...

Comment: Thanks for for your reply. Could you please elaborate the 1st option as could not understand it. The 2nd option is out of question as their would be a great deal of pipeline involved and would defeat the whole purpose of inserting the comments by the tool.

Comment: Pt1: Basicly you could create the code along with comments using a macro preprocessor like m4, maybe the c preprocessor or lisp/scheme. Maybe xml and a stylesheet. A very good tool for this purpose may be temgen [link](http://temgen.berlios.de/).